# Cannot use smartcard reader with protocol type T=CL using pcsc-sharp

Tags: c#, smartcard, apdu, pcsc

I recently acquired an ACS ACR122U card reader for use in an upcoming project. The only trouble is that I cannot send APDU commands to it using `pcsc-sharp` - I just get an `PCSC.InvalidProtocolException` every time I try, no matter what protocol I select as the argument when constructing the `CommandApdu` object. The reader uses a T=CL protocol according to the ACR122UTool included in the SDK. Is there any way I can use it from `pcsc-sharp`, or do I have to do it another way?

Comment: toby code can you please help me in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47468009/express-js-smart-card-authentication

Answer (score 0):

According to [the source code](https://github.com/danm-de/pcsc-sharp/blob/RELEASE_3_5_1/pcsc-sharp/Enums/SCardProtocol.cs), pcsc-sharp only supports the protocols T=0, T=1, T=15 and raw.